# How would you explain the risks of the $Log$ keyword?

Tags: version-control, keyword

I seem to get into an annual debate about the use of the `$Log$` keyword.  My point of view is this:

`$Log$` is white hot death.

All it does is jam marginally relevant spam into your source files.  Any information that anyone thinks they might be able to get from a $Log$ is more readily available from (and is likely to be more accurate in) your version control system.

So, here's the question: how would you explain to an "old school" coder (who thinks that $Log$ is the way to manage source code changes) that we have better tools now?

[The CVSNT remarks on $Log$ are a good start](http://www.cvsnt.org/manual/html/Log-keyword.html) but they're just not pointed enough.  To date, the closest that I've come to a  one-liner that I've managed to come up with is "`$Log$` is a wish.  You're *hoping* that what gets spammed into your file has *any* relation to what really happened to this file."

*PS for clarity: when I say "old school," I mean old in attitude, not old in years.  My first programming paycheck (and a remarkably modest one it was, too) was sometime in 1986 and I never thought $Log$ was a good idea.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the [Subversion FAQ](http://subversion.tigris.org/faq.html#log-in-source) also has a good explanation.

> $Log$ is a total horror the moment you start merging changes
>   between branches. You're practically guaranteed to get conflicts there,
>   which -- because of the nature of this keyword -- simply cannot be
>   resolved automatically.

Comment: Very nice - I didn't find that one in my quick search.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to what the others have said, try putting a comment (/* ... */) into a commit message :->.

Comment: Okay, that's just funny.  Mean, but funny.

Answer (score 2):

The amount of useful bits in a source file slowly decreases as changes are made to it with that $Log$ statement in it.  We had it in some files that came from CVS and number of lines of $Log$ statements was on the order of 10x longer than the executable code in file actually was.  And it had a few groups of duplicates caused by bad merging from some branches.

Answer (score 1):

You may consider (emphasis on *may*) embedding *immutable* meta-data in your file.
(See the debate between me and an "older schooler" : [Embedded Version Numbers - Good or Evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645008/what-are-the-basic-clearcase-concepts-every-developer-should-know/645424#645424)).

Even though I have always considered that practice as evil (mixing meta-data information into data), introducing "merge hell", one could argue that it could work, with the right merge manager, for **immutable meta-data with a fixed format**, like:

- $Revision$     $Revision: 9.13 $
- $Date$         $Date: 2009/03/06 06:52:26 $
- $RCSfile$      $RCSfile: stderr.c,v $

But mutable meta-data like logs ? With unknown format or content ? That is bound to fail.

Comment: I actually like the $Id: $ keyword because it is pretty much a last-one-wins tag.  If any change was committed, there will be some sort of delta.  It's also nicely low bandwidth.